# How to identify each button in table row?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, button, tablerow

I want buttons in table row to show different titles depending on database values.

But I am facing issue in uniquely identifying each buttons i.e button 0, button 1 etc.

Note, button is in table row.

Comment: @vaibhav hey when i navigate through some views and come back to this view selected buttons previously are not shown selected. That is what my issue is.

Comment: Check this thread. I've tried to explain it there: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4725726/putting-two-buttons-in-table-view-cell/7198730#7198730

Comment: Check this thread. I've tried to explain it.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4725726/putting-two-buttons-in-table-view-cell/7198730#7198730

Comment: Check this thread. I've tried to explain it:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4725726/putting-two-buttons-in-table-view-cell/7198730#7198730

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To uniquely identify the buttons in TAbleView you need to **set the tag of each & every button**
like

This this out,this will definitely solve your problem :)

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
    }

        UIButton *CameraBreak=[[UIButton alloc]init];
        CameraBreak.frame=CGRectMake(28, 33, 60, 40);
        CameraBreak.tag=indexPath.row;
        [CameraBreak setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Camera.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

        [CameraBreak addTarget:self action:@selector(CameraBtn_Clicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside]; 
        [cell.contentView addSubview:CameraBreak];
            //[CameraBreak release]; 
    return cell;
    }


-(IBAction)CameraBtn_Clicked:(id)sender
{
    NSLog(@"%d",[sender tag]); /This will print the tag of button which you have pressed in TableView
}
```

Either for Dynamic Records use the Following link :

[How to Select particular check Box in tableView which is inserted in table cell interface builder in iphone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5415732/how-to-select-particular-check-box-in-tableview-which-is-inserted-in-table-cell-i/5415843#5415843)

Now that will work

Comment: hey this is ok but i am facing issue in assigning say image0 to button in first row then image1 to button in second row, then say image0 to button in fifth row etc. depending on the values coming from database

1 value in DB -image1
0 value in DB - image0

Comment: hey Dude so can you please tell, whether the total number of records in DB is fixed or it's variable ?? Because I no this will not work to for setting the image but one could be able to get the tag of each Button.

Comment: check the ans I have edited my answer & try to follow that link if it solves your problem.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at this thread [how-to-select-particular-check-box-in-tableview-which-is-inserted-in-table-cell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5415732/how-to-select-particular-check-box-in-tableview-which-is-inserted-in-table-cell-i/5415843#5415843)

Answer (score 0):

use the NSObject property "tag" ... e.g.

```
 UIButton* myButton;
 myButton.tag = EON; OR myButton.tag = EOFF ;

if(myButton.tag == EON)
{
   myButton.tag = EOFF; 
  //Do As per your requirement 
}
else if(myButton.tag == EOFF)
{
  myButton.tag = EON; 
  //Do As per your requirement 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use table indexpath.row + your own values (0,1,2...) as tag to each button.
I m not sure but atleast you can try.