# How to detect indexPath for tableView using tagged buttons and custom class

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

What I am trying to do:
I have a view controller with a table in it and that table is controlled by a custom class called protoCell. Here is my ViewController code:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("pCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! protoCell

    return cell

}
```

The output of this table is just 3 rows with two buttons. The buttons are controlled by a custom class which here is the code for that:

```
//
//  protoCell.swift
//  Handling Cells

import UIKit

class protoCell: UITableViewCell {

var isPressed = [0, 0]

@IBOutlet var button: UIButton!

@IBAction func buttonPress(sender: AnyObject) {

    if isPressed[sender.tag] == 0 {

        isPressed[sender.tag] = 1

    } else {

        isPressed[sender.tag] = 0

    }

    println(isPressed)

}

}
```

I have the buttons mapped to the same pressed action and managed by tags. When a button is pressed it marks down which button was pressed. In the main ViewController I want to know which buttons are pressed as well as which row (because the buttons would correspond to different values based upon which row the user is tapping).

I searched here a lot and couldn't find how to do this while managing the cells using a custom class.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked for me. I had similar requirement as yours.

```
//Create a variable in your class for indexPath
var customIndexPath: NSIndexPath = NSIndexPath()

//Set the value of indexPath to customIndexPath in your tableView function
customIndexPath = indexPath


// You can use this customIndexPath as given in the examples below:
self.array.removeAtIndex(customIndexPath.row)
self.tableName.reloadSections(NSIndexSet(index: customIndexPath.section), withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimation.Fade)
self.tableName.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths([customIndexPath], withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimation.Top)
```

I have used this in similar way

```
func btnOKClicked(sender:UIButton) {
        if sender.tag == 1
        {
            self.tabBarController!.tabBar.userInteractionEnabled = true
            println("Successful")
        }
        else if sender.tag == 2
        {
            self.tabBarController!.tabBar.userInteractionEnabled = true
            self.tableName.reloadSections(NSIndexSet(index: customIndexPath.section), withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimation.Fade)
            self.activityIndicator.stopAnimating()

        }
        else if sender.tag == 3
        {
            self.tabBarController!.tabBar.userInteractionEnabled = true
            var labelone = self.stringArray[customIndexPath.row]
            self.deleteFromLocal(labelone)
            self.arrary2.removeAtIndex(customIndexPath.row)

            self.tableName.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths([customIndexPath], withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimation.Top)

            self.tableName.reloadSections(NSIndexSet(index: customIndexPath.section), withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimation.Fade)

        }

        println("customIndexPath :   customIndexPath :::::::\(customIndexPath)")



        println("btnOKClicked")
    }
```

Hope this might be helpful.

Comment: I am not wanting to delete the line of the array at the index path but want to link that index path to the isPressed array in the custom class. So I want to know the array for the custom class for the first row is [0, 1] where as the array for the second row might be [1, 1]. Also if you can think of a better way to link the custom class buttons (buttons displayed in the prototype cell) with their corresponding row that would be welcomed as well.

Comment: You can add tag to the button as button.tag = indexPath.Row . In this case if the indexPath.row is 0 then button on the first cell is clicked.

Comment: Yes but there are two buttons on each cell and both buttons are the same and are controlled by the same action. So a simple example of what I'm going after (and maybe you already answered it and I'm not getting it).

Cell 1 is a question that says "Do you like coffee or tea?" [] Yes [] No. The buttons are boxes next to yes and no.

Cell 2 "Do you like the color green?" [] Yes [] No.

The questions are dynamic and pulled from a table and I know that cell.messageText.text[indexPath.row] corresponds to the question and I want to know the button tags that correspond to each question.

Comment: Check this link -http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4725726/two-buttons-in-a-uitableviewcell-how-to-tell-which-indexpath-was-selected

Comment: Thanks I marked your answer as correct. It actually brings me to this follow up question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32085737/selected-button-in-cell-is-showing-up-on-reuse-cells-also-using-sender-tag-for

Answer (score 0):

You say "The output of this table is just 3 rows with two buttons. The buttons are controlled by a custom class which here is the code for that"

For this type of task, a static table view may be much easier.

To do this:

In the story board go to your TableView (inside the UITableViewCotroller). In the Attribute Inspector choose Content = static cells.

when you do this, you can draw each cell individually with buttons and you can connect your Buttons directly with your class in the storyboard (@IBOutlet and @IBAction)

You'll find many good tutorials with the keywords "static table view".

Comment: My cells are dynamic, I just said the number 3 as an example. It could be any number of rows but this problem only has one column.