# Selected button in cell is showing up on reuse cells - also using sender.tag for button distinction

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, uitableview, xcode6

I have a bunch of rows in a table and each row consists of 6 UIButtons (they are checkbox images). I started with just trying to get one button to work before linking all of them and that worked somewhat. The code would update the image to a checked box if I clicked on it and if I scrolled down and back up the first cell first box would be the only one checked. If I repeatedly scroll up and down though, it will randomly unselect that first cell first box. Here is my ViewController code:

```
//
//  TestViewController.swift
//

import UIKit
import Parse



class TestViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate {

@IBOutlet var tableView: UITableView!


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

}

func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {

    return 1
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    return 10

}


func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! protoCell

    configure(cell, forRowAtIndexPath: indexPath)

    cell.customIndexPath = indexPath

    return cell

}



func configure(cell: protoCell, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

    if cell.selectedIndexPaths.containsObject(indexPath) {

        println("Contains")
        let image = UIImage(named: "checkedbox.png")
        cell.button.setImage(image, forState: .Normal)
        println(cell.selectedIndexPaths)

    } else {

        println("Not Contains")
        let image = UIImage(named: "checkbox.png")
        cell.button.setImage(image, forState: .Normal)

    }



}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


}
```

I am controlling the table using a custom cocoa class for my UITableViewCell which has the code here:

```
//
//  protoCell.swift
//  ParseStarterProject
//

import UIKit

class protoCell: UITableViewCell {

var selectedIndexPaths = NSMutableSet()

var customIndexPath: NSIndexPath = NSIndexPath()

var isPressed = [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]

@IBOutlet var button: UIButton!

@IBAction func buttonPressed(sender: AnyObject) {

    println(isPressed[sender.tag])

    if isPressed[sender.tag] == 1 {

        isPressed[sender.tag] = 2
        let image = UIImage(named: "checkedbox.png")
        sender.setImage(image, forState: .Normal)
        selectedIndexPaths.addObject(customIndexPath)

    } else {

        isPressed[sender.tag] = 1
        let image = UIImage(named: "checkbox.png")
        sender.setImage(image, forState: .Normal)
        selectedIndexPaths.removeObject(customIndexPath)

    }

    println(isPressed)

}

}
```

I know the code is wrong because of what I am seeing. Also all images besides the first button are repeating. I am not too familiar with Objective-C so some of the searching has been hard.

Any help would be great!

Comment: How many buttons are there in a cell?

Comment: There are six buttons in a cell

Comment: OK, now I think you figured out what is going wrong. When you scroll, actually the table view will try to re use the cells,  and thus you see unwanted behaviour here. Correct way is to maintain, the cell states in a separate array outside of your cells. and then map that to the cell for a given row.  The row index into your array should fetch right state for right cell.

Comment: Yes and that is what I attempted to do but it didn't work. Do you have any insight into what changes I could make to the above code for the functionality to work correctly?

Comment: Come up with a simple model object called as Config. Let the each config maintain states of 6 buttons for a given cell. Have an array of 10 config objects (for 10 rows you want). Now ensure cell at a given row maps to the right config in this array. Maintain this array in table view controller. Every time you configure cell, pass it the right config object, and let it modify the state within this object whenever a button is pressed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please see the skeleton code below (I just typed here, and not tested) that should give your a fair idea as to what needs be done-

```
 class Config{
      enum ButtonState : Int {
        case NoneSelected,
        case Button1Selected,
        case Button2Selected,
        case Button3Selected,
        case Button4Selected,
        case Button5Selected,
        case Button6Selected
      }
       var buttonState : Int = . NoneSelected
    }

//Within TableView controller, maintain an array of 10 such objects
var configs = [ButtonState(), ButtonState(), ButtonState(), ButtonState(), ButtonState(), ButtonState(), ButtonState(), ButtonState(), ButtonState(), ButtonState()]

//This is how you need to configure the cell now-
func configure(cell: protoCell, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

  //First deselect all buttons
   DeselectAllButtons()

  //Get proper config object
   var config = configs[indexPath.row]
   //Maintain a ref to the config in the cell.
   self.config = config

   switch config. buttonState{
   case . NoneSelected
    DeselectAllButtons()
   case let x where (x & Button1Selected) == true
     SelectButton(button1)
      case let x where (x & Button1Selected) == true
     SelectButton(button1)
   case let x where (x & Button2Selected) == true
     SelectButton(button3)
   case let x where (x & Button3Selected) == true
     SelectButton(button3)
   case let x where (x & Button4Selected) == true
     SelectButton(button4)
   case let x where (x & Button5Selected) == true
     SelectButton(button5)
   case let x where (x & Button1Selected) == true
     SelectButton(button6)
   default:
     DeselectAllButtons()
  }
} 

 //And your action in cell can be-
func buttonPressed(sender: AnyObject){
    switch sender{
      case button1
      self.config.buttonState  |= .Button1Selected
      case button2
      self.config.buttonState  |= .Button2Selected
      case button3
      self.config.buttonState  |= .Button3Selected
      case button4
      self.config.buttonState  |= .Button4Selected
      case button5
      self.config.buttonState  |= .Button5Selected
      case button6
      self.config.buttonState  |= .Button6Selected
    }

}
```